# How to use AtomicInteger for a situation with comparement

Tags: java, thread-safety, atomic

I have an AtomicInteger variable:

```
AtomicInteger aInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

One of the threads that access the variable needs to check its value and based on it to call a function. Here is what i mean.

```
if(aInteger < maxAvailableConnectionSlots)
{
   aInteger.incrementAndGet();
   doSomething();
}
else
{
  doSomething2();
}
```

So my question is how can i make the above code thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (untested):

```
do {
  prev = aInteger.get();
  next = prev + 1;
} while (prev < maxAvailableConnections && !aInteger.compareAndSet(prev, next));

boolean wasIncremented = prev < maxAvailableConnections;
if (wasIncremented) doSomething();
else doSomething2();
```

Note that `aInteger` may change between the loop and the if/else, but you will only call `doSomething` if you actually incremented `aInteger`.